# Laravel 5 Dotenv for specific subdomain

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpdotenv

I have a few subdomain in my laravel 5 application, each sub domain have a specific configuration, like mail, nocaptcha, etc.

how to set .env file to work with my-specific subdomain ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use separate `.env` files for each subdomain so if you use env variables in your config it will work without great modifications.

Create `bootstrap/env.php` file with the following content:

```
<?php
$app->detectEnvironment(function () use ($app) {
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
        Dotenv::load($app['path.base'], $app->environmentFile());
    }

    $pos = mb_strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.');
    $prefix = '';
    if ($pos) {
        $prefix = mb_substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, $pos);
    }
    $file = '.' . $prefix . '.env';

    if (!file_exists($app['path.base'] . '/' . $file)) {
        $file = '.env';
    }

    Dotenv::load($app['path.base'], $file);
});
```

Now modify `bootstrap/app.php` to load your custom `env.php` file. Just add:

```
require('env.php');
```

after

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

Now you can create separate env files for each domains for example if you use `testing.app`, `abc.testing.app` and `def.testing.app` you can have `.env` file for main domain (and for all subdomains that don't have custom env files) and `.abc.env` and `.def.env` files for custom env variables your your subdomains.

Comment: @Artistan Probably you are using  newer version of framework and you need to load it in different way (this is post from over 1 year).

Comment: Many Thanks, 
it was very helpful to build my solution, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880331/laravel-5-dotenv-for-specific-subdomain/40310276#40310276), this works for laravel 5.2 :) 

Greetings

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I found is to use .htaccess plus env variables.

In **.htaccess** add these lines:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'sub.domain'">
    SetEnv APP_DOMAIN sub
</If>
```

In **bootstrap/app.php** add after the app initialisation:

```
//own env directory for separate env files
$app->useEnvironmentPath( realpath(__DIR__ . '/../env/') );
//separate files for each domain (see htaccess)
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom( getenv('APP_DOMAIN') . '.env' );
```

Create a new directory called "env" in your Laravel root and add your config files as:

- "sub1.env",
- "sub2.env" ..etc

(Of course you can keep it in your root as is currently, but for many subdomains it's better to move into a directory => looks much cleaner => everyone's happy! :) )

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. Each subdomain will be running in the same environment.

If you want per-subdomain configuration then your best bet is to either create a configuration file in the **config** directory with each subdomain’s settings, or use a database approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, Based on @Marcin's answer I built this one (Works with laravel 5.2.X)

I added in the bootstrap/app.php

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    $hostArray = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    //if the address is a subdomain and exist the .xxx.env file
    $envFile = sprintf('.%s.env', $hostArray[0]);
    if (count($hostArray) >  2 && file_exists(sprintf('%s/%s', $app['path.base'], $envFile))) {
        $app->loadEnvironmentFrom($envFile);
    }
}
```

after

`$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);`

I hope that helps someone

Greetings

Comment: Just notice that HTTP_HOST might not be always set. For example, when you run artisan command it won't be set